# Cakephp 2.x set custom validation message in Controller without Model

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

**Code in View**

```
<?= $this->Form->input('ProductGroupImage.image', array("class" => "", "type" => "file")); ?>
```

Here **ProductGroupImage** is just alias not a actual model.

**In Controller**

```
$this->validationErrors['ProductGroupImage']['image'] = "File not Valid"
```

Above Code does not show Error message in view.

Answer (score -1):

i assume that you are triggering the validation on model and then you updating your validationErrors array.

```
if (!$this->ProductGroupImage->validates()) {
    $errors = $this->ProductGroupImage->validationErrors;
}
```

You can then update the errors variable and the reassign it to the validationErrors.

```
if (isset($this->ProductGroupImage->validationErrors['execused_referral_by'])) {
$errors['execused_referral_by'] = "Please Select Excused By";
}

$this->Tardy->validationErrors = $errors;
```

Comment: ProductGroupImage is not a model